# Kuwait transit visa

Tags: usa, indian-citizens

am travelling to USA via Kuwait and the layover is 5 hours.

I am Indian citizen and have valid USA Visa B1/B2 valid for the next 7 years.

Please update me I have to book a flight and need some help.